# Should I use "für" in "Ich gehe für zwei Wochen zurück nach Hause"

Tags: preposition, time

I want to say "I will go back home (in another country) for two weeks"

> (a) Ich gehe für zwei Wochen zurück nach Hause
>
> (b) Ich gehe zwei Wochen zurück nach Hause

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ones are correct. The first gains the time aspect a bit more. And it prevents the misunderstanding it could take 2 weeks to go home.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could also say

> "Ich werde für zwei Wochen heimkehren."

From my understanding you need a form of 'werden' to talk in future tense. I assume you meant that when you wrote "I want to say *I **will** go back home...*". Plus *heimkehren* means "to return home" so it seems pretty all inclusive for what you want to say.

This website has example sentences with using *heimkehren* and that's why I think it's a better verb for your example. Maybe even *zurückkehren* might work.

http://en.bab.la/dictionary/german-english/heimkehren

Comment: As it is true that [*heimkehren*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heimkehren) does indeed cover the meaning it nevertheless is a bit old fashioned to say. *"Nach Hause gehen/fahren/kommen"* is far more often used in contemporary German.

Comment: @Takkat: Oh I see! I'm glad you told me. I found this verb because this question made me think about the verb zurueckkehren. I had read the verb in my vocab book and saw that it means 'to return', but I wasn't sure it was right for this context. I looked it up and came across heimkkehren. Again, good thing you commented because I'd prolly sound pretty strange saying it, lol. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: If you like you can add this by an [edit] to your answer but note that *heimkehren* is not wrong ;)

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct, but rather than b) I would say

> "Ich gehe zwei Wochen lang zurück nach Hause."

or

> "Ich gehe zwei Wochen lang heim."

Answer (score 0):

## Standard Germany German

I'd usually provide a time. Ich würde eine Zeitangabe angeben. Otherwise it sounds like your journey home will take you two weeks. It also sounds derived from English. Admitted I like CreeperNation's answer. It does not seem old fashion to me--very much in fashion.

> "Ich bin *[dann]* *[ab Morgen]* zwei Wochen daheim/zu Hause."
>
> "Ich werde *[dann]* zwei Wochen daheim bleiben/sein/wohnen."
>
> "Ich werde zwei Wochen zu Hause beleiben/sein/wohnen...*[bevor ich wieder abfliege.]*"

## Upland Tyrolean (Southern Bavarian German / Südbairisch):

> "I bin *[Morga]* zwoa Wochen dahuam...*[bevor i wieder ofliega]*."
>
> "I gea zwoa Wochen dahuam, dann bin I wieder weg."

(with nice monothong *i* and *e* in *wieder* and finish it off with a nice hard [k] at the end ;)