# Wann benutzt man "Für drei Tage", "von drei Tage" und "drei Tage"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, preposition

Wann benutzt man „für“ oder „von“ mit Zeitangabe oder nur die Zeitangabe, um „for 3 days“ auf Deutsch zu schreiben?
Zum Beispiel der Satz “I've waited for you for 2 hours.“ ist „Ich habe 2 Stunden auf dich gewartet.“ auf Deutsch, oder?
In diesem Satz schreibt man weder „für“ noch „von“. Aber wann nutzt man denn die Präpositionen?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/the-use-of-schon-schon-seit-and-f%c3%bcr-for-periods-of-time and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8247/should-i-use-f%c3%bcr-in-ich-gehe-f%c3%bcr-zwei-wochen-zur%c3%bcck-nach-hause

Answer (score 3):

Das kommt auf den Kontext an und kann pauschal nicht beantwortet werden.

Beispiel

> I've been waiting for you for three days.
>   Ich habe drei Tage auf Dich gewartet. *oder manchmal auch*
>   Seit drei Tagen warte ich auf Dich.

Es gibt aber auch:

> I have enough food and water for three days.
>   Ich habe genug Essen und Wasser für drei Tage.

Man kann also nicht pauschal sagen, wie *for 3 days* oder ähnliche Angaben zu übersetzen sind, ohne den kompletten Satz zu kennen.

Es ist aber klar, dass *von* in jedem Fall falsch ist.

Answer (score 3):

## Past Events (open/incomplete)

English uses "for" and "since" for referring to stretches of time in the past up to a relatively current point in time. German uses "since" (seit) for both of these cases.

I have been waiting for you for three days.

> Ich warte seit drei Tagen auf dich.

I have been waiting for you since Tuesday.

> Ich warte seit Dienstag auf dich.

Note that "seit" is most often accompanied by a verb in the present tense (It is my opinion that German emphasizes the moment, while English uses the perfect tense, which emphasizes the stretch of time.)

## Timespans with *für*

When do you use "für" in German for timespans then? When referring to absolute spans of time ("food for three days") instead of relative ones ("waiting for three days [before something happened, e.g. this conversation]"). See Thorstens answer.

## *von + bis*

It is unclear what you want with "von", but perhaps a *von + bis* construction is what you're looking for:

> Ich werde von Montag bis [auf] Dienstag auf dich warten.

## Past Events (closed/completed)

Just *drei Tage* (+lang): I [had] waited for you for 3 days before I started.

> Ich habe drei Tage [lang] auf dich gewartet, bevor ich angefangen habe.

Comment: Für Zeiträume wird häufiger *xyz lang* verwendet, zum Beispiel *drei Tage lang*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Stimmt. Meine Antwort wurde entsprechend angepasst.

Comment: Another thing: I think *bis auf Dienstag* is only used in some dialects. Normally you'd omit the *auf*,  except in phrases like *Montag bis Freitag, bis auf Dienstag*, but that means something different (*auser*). You **can** say *Montag auf Dienstag*, however. Did you mean that? If so, use a slash instead of square brackets to make clear it's an alternative to *bis*.

Comment: " 'Seit' most often takes the present tense" this must be a typo, since "seit" isn't a verb.

Comment: @Beta It is not a typo. "take" refers to a following verb, not to *seit* itself. I will adjust the text to make that explicit, although this is normally how language teachers talk ;)